# How to fail SQL query when using partial three part name like dbname..tablename

Tags: sql-server

I need a way to fail my query when there is partial three part name is involved like
select * from dbName..TableName in SQL Server

Thank you.

Comment: Set everyone's default schema to a "silly" one with no objects? (Won't stop `sysadmin`s though, but they *should* know better.) This seems like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) to me though.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a little in jest, but it *will* give you the desired effect. But, like I said in my comment. This feels like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Firstly, create a new schema in your database. I am intentionally giving is a silly name:

```
USE YourDatabase;
GO

CREATE SCHEMA Always_define_your_schema;
GO
```

Then change all the `USER`s in the database to have their default schema be this new ("stupid") schema:

```
ALTER USER YourUser WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = Always_define_your_schema;
```

If you want to do this to every `USER` with a script, you could do something like this:

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

SET @SQL = STUFF((SELECT NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
                         N'ALTER USER ' + QUOTENAME(U.[name]) + N' WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = Always_define_your_schema;'
                  FROM sys.database_principals U
                  WHERE U.type IN ('U','S')
                    AND U.authentication_type > 0
                    AND U.[name] != 'dbo' --You will need to likely include more here
                  FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,2,N'');

PRINT @SQL; --Your debugging friend

--EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL; --Uncomment to run
```

But, like I said, this is more of a "jest" answer; if you really implement this then expect to break things...

Comment: Thank you for suggestion but i already did this thing and it did not worked, My query picked the tabled with schema=dbo. I want one of my login not to go further with execution when <dbname>..<tables> (without specifying schema) is founf in my SP.

Comment: With respect, @PareshMaru , *if* the `USER` has a default schema defined, and they have reconnected since the change was made, it would only use the `dbo` schema by default if the `LOGIN` didn't have a `USER` mapped (was `guest` or a `dbo` due to being a `sysadmin`). Which implies, if they had reconnected and have a mapped `USER` the implementation wasn't correct. Don't forget, you would have to do this in *every* user database, not just one.

Comment: If you connect as the `LOGIN` to the respective database, @PareshMaru , and run `SELECT DP.[name], DP.default_schema_name
FROM sys.database_principals DP
WHERE DP.name = CURRENT_USER;` what do you get?

Comment: When i run your query by with new Login, i get default schema name as the different schema that i set for that login. but i try to run my original query i.e (SELECT * FROM MyDb..MyTable), it still references the dbo schema and query does not fail.

Comment: Then either the `LOGIN` you were using didn't have it's `USER`'s schema changed, or it's mapped to `dbo` (which I advised at the start this won't work for). But, again, this is just an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: I did mapped the new login with newly created schema as its default schema. But again no luck.

Comment: If you had, then you would be getting an error, @PareshMaru . Also, you didn't actually respond with the result of the SQL I asked you to run...